# Bypass firewall with server

Tags: ip

Right now device A(workstation) is trying to get the device C(sever/client) but of course theres a firewall that blocks the ip and port.. This cannot be changed. However device A can get to device B (server)  and B can get to device C  due to firewall rules.  If firewall cannot be change but device B acts as the middle man what does device B need yo connect A to B to C? All 3 devices are on different subnets but firewall rules connect A toB B to C.

Comment: I guess that firewall has a purpose. Why don't you talk to it's administrator to allow traffic from A to C?

Comment: No software on B is going to be able to defeat the firewall on C. Either open up the firewall or move the server software.

Comment: Tunnel traffic. What service are you trying to reach, and why do you need to work around security?